# Buddypress custom fields when create new grup, no work

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I want add some custom field when i create new grup, (I used for countdown)
**but it does not work when create new group**, it only works when edit groups.

And I have this code :

````
function save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput($group_id) {
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_group_textinput']) ) {
        if ( $group_id == 0 ) { 
            $group_id = buddypress()->groups->new_group_id; 
        }elseif(bp_get_current_group_id() > 0) {
            $group_id = bp_get_current_group_id();
        }
        $text_input_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_group_textinput']);  
        groups_update_groupmeta($group_id, 'custom_group_textinput', $text_input_value);
    }
}
add_action('groups_group_after_save', 'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');
add_action('groups_group_create_complete', 'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');
add_action('groups_group_edit_save_complete', 'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');```


 my code is designed to save custom fields in BuddyPress groups when a group is created or edited. However, i mentioned that it's not working when creating a new group. 

$group_id become 0 and not working
````

Comment: Use this hook and write a new function due to passing 2 arguments: `do_action( 'groups_created_group', $group->id, $group );`

Comment: @shanebp thank you, was work .  
function save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput($group_id = 0, $group = null) { ... +
add_action('groups_created_group',   'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code:

```
// Funcția pentru adăugarea câmpului text la formularul de creare/actualizare al grupului
function custom_buddypress_group_textinput() {
    // Asigurați-vă că sunteți într-o pagină de creare sau editare a grupului BuddyPress
    if (bp_is_group_create() || bp_is_group_admin_page()) {
        $group_id = bp_get_current_group_id();
        $custom_group_textinput = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, 'custom_group_textinput' );
        ?>
        <label for="custom_group_textinput">Time Remaining:</label> <?php // echo strtotime($custom_group_textinput); // timestamp ?>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="custom_group_textinput"  id="custom_group_textinput" value="<?php echo $custom_group_textinput; ?>" required />
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('bp_after_group_details_creation_step', 'custom_buddypress_group_textinput');

function save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput($group_id = 0, $group = null) {
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_group_textinput']) ) {
        if ( $group_id == 0 ) { 
            $group_id = buddypress()->groups->new_group_id; 
        }elseif(bp_get_current_group_id() > 0) {
            $group_id = bp_get_current_group_id();
        }
        $text_input_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_group_textinput']);  
        groups_update_groupmeta($group_id, 'custom_group_textinput', $text_input_value);
    }
}
add_action('groups_group_after_save', 'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');
add_action('groups_created_group',   'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');
add_action('groups_group_create_complete', 'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');
add_action('groups_group_edit_save_complete', 'save_custom_buddypress_group_textinput');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).